# Plotting tiles of nighttime lights from multiple h5 files into one big map

Tags: python, geospatial, h5py, cartopy, satellite-image

I am trying to create a map of nighttime lights for Europe. Data source is [NASA](https://ladsweb.modaps.eosdis.nasa.gov/search/order/1) and I am using their VNP46A1 data for 2022/03/27 (you can find the exact files in [my Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/psd2yq68w0vd1i98i5vb6/h?dl=0&rlkey=xp1nsogscwet3xbx8vj395o9n), too). For downloading the data, I select the whole EU region which results in about 14 separate files or "tiles". I managed to read in and plot the files individually, but I don't know how to put them together to get one big map of the whole European region. I'm not sure what keywords I should search for because I'm totally unfamiliar with this kind of file format and plotting something like this. Below is my working code for plotting a single file (adapted from [this Medium article](https://medium.com/the-barometer/plotting-noaa-dnb-nighttime-data-using-python-h5py-cartopy-daefef240b0f)).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import h5py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import os
from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import glob

indir = 'D:/PYTHON/NASA/VNP46A1.A2023058.h17v03.001.2023060025350.h5'
data = h5py.File(indir)
list(data.keys())
dnb = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB/Data Fields/DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m']
dnb = np.array(dnb)
dnb = np.where(dnb==65535, np.nan, dnb)
# np.nanmax(dnb)

lat_max = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['NorthBoundingCoord']
lat_min = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['SouthBoundingCoord']
lon_min = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['WestBoundingCoord']
lon_max = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['EastBoundingCoord']

lats = np.linspace(lat_max, lat_min, dnb.shape[1])
lons = np.linspace(lon_min, lon_max, dnb.shape[0])
x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)

cmap = plt.get_cmap('cividis')
crs = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig =  plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = plt.axes(projection=crs)
ax.coastlines(resolution='10m', color='white',alpha=0.5)
ax.pcolormesh(x, y, dnb, cmap = cmap, vmin = 0, vmax = 100)

plt.xlim()

gl = ax.gridlines(crs=crs, draw_labels=True, alpha=0.5)
gl.xlabels_top = None
gl.ylabels_left = None
xgrid = np.arange(lon_min-2, lon_max+2, 2.)
ygrid = np.arange(lat_min-2, lat_max+2, 2.)
gl.xlocator = mticker.FixedLocator(xgrid.tolist())
gl.ylocator = mticker.FixedLocator(ygrid.tolist())
gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
gl.xlabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}
gl.ylabel_style = {'size': 10, 'color': 'black'}

plt.xlim((lon_min,lon_max))
plt.ylim((lat_min,lat_max))

plt.show()
```

This is the output I get after running the above code:

[image]

My desired end result would be something like this:

[image]

[source](https://worldview.earthdata.nasa.gov/?v=-31.7416807404325,27.545806602863852,52.33688618805466,70.89881767536505&z=1&l=Reference_Labels_15m(hidden),Reference_Features_15m,Coastlines_15m,VIIRS_SNPP_DayNightBand_At_Sensor_Radiance,BlueMarble_NextGeneration(hidden),VIIRS_SNPP_CorrectedReflectance_TrueColor&lg=false&sh=VIIRS_SNPP_DayNightBand_At_Sensor_Radiance,C1897815356-LAADS&t=2022-02-27-T14%3A59%3A42Z)

I thought about plotting in a loop but that took very long and yielded incorrect results in the end.

Comment: I plotted 2 different files and discovered the values of North/South/East/West BoundingCoords are different. So, I checked all the files and discovered each coversa 10x10 grid. Overall range for all 16 files is -10 to +30 long / +30 to +60 lat. To plot as one image, you will have to properly size array `dnb`, and loop over the files. As you read each file, use the max/mins to map the data into the appropriate array indices using NumPy slice notation for array `dnb`. Now that you understand the data, do you need help with the slice notation?

Comment: @kcw78  I should've mentioned the lat and lon ranges would be different for each file, thanks for checking that. And yes, would very much appreciate help with the slice notation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, this was more work than I expected. I tried to write a generic procedure (not dependent on latitude/longitude range. Mapping HDF5 DNB data to the NumPy `dnb` array got too complicated. (And, there were a few matplotlib and cartopy surprises along the way.) Code and image are at the end.

First, a clarification about the data. There are 20 files (It's a grid of 5x4 datasets/images.). Each covers a 10 deg x 10 deg grid. Overall lat/lon range of the files is +30 to +70 latitude and -10 to +30 longitude. To plot as one image, the `x, y, and dnb` arrays have to be sized to hold all 20 datasets, and the HDF5 DNB datasets have to be mapped to the `dnb` array.

Here is the procedure:

1. Loop over the files to get the max/min for latitude and longitude. (Since you  know the range, you could skip this step and hard code the values.) I also get the DNB dataset type and shape, and use to size the `x, y, and dnb` arrays.
2. Create the `x and y` arrays using the min/max longitude and latitude from values above.
3. Loop over over the files (again) to read the DNB data and map to the
   `dnb` array using slice notation. I hard coded the slicing indices. (It could be done more elegantly.)
4. Once the data is loaded, the matplotlib / cartopy procedure is almost the same -- only a few lines have to be changed to account for the map extents for
   all 20 files.

Code for each step below:

**Step 1 - Get the max/min latitude/longitude values:**

```
folder = 'D:/PYTHON/NASA'
h5files = glob.glob(folder+'/*.h5')
n_files = len(h5files)
n_files_lon = 5
n_files_lat = 4
lat_lon_arr = np.empty(shape=(n_files,4)) 
for i, h5file in enumerate(h5files):
    with h5py.File(h5file) as h5f:
        dnb_attr_ds = h5f['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB']
        lat_min = dnb_attr_ds.attrs['SouthBoundingCoord'][0]
        lat_max = dnb_attr_ds.attrs['NorthBoundingCoord'][0]
        lon_min = dnb_attr_ds.attrs['WestBoundingCoord'][0]
        lon_max = dnb_attr_ds.attrs['EastBoundingCoord'][0]
        lat_lon_arr[i] = [round(lat_min), round(lat_max), round(lon_min), round(lon_max)]
        dnb_ds = h5f['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB/Data Fields/DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m']
        dnb_ds_shape = dnb_ds.shape

map_lat_min = np.amin(lat_lon_arr[:,0])
map_lat_max = np.amax(lat_lon_arr[:,1])
map_lon_min = np.amin(lat_lon_arr[:,2])
map_lon_max = np.amax(lat_lon_arr[:,3])
print(f'map_lat_min= {map_lat_min:.1f}, map_lat_max={map_lat_max:.1f}', 
      f'map_lon_min={map_lon_min:.1f}, map_lon_max= {map_lon_max:.1f}\n')
```

**Step 2 - Create the x and y arrays from min/max longitude and latitude values above:**

```
lats = np.linspace(map_lat_max, map_lat_min, n_files_lat*dnb_ds_shape[1])#.astype(np.float32)
lons = np.linspace(map_lon_min, map_lon_max, n_files_lon*dnb_ds_shape[0])#.astype(np.float32)
x, y = np.meshgrid(lons, lats)
```

**Step 3 - Create the dnb array and load H5 DNB data into it:**

```
dnb = np.empty(shape=x.shape,dtype=np.uint16)

cnt_lat, cnt_lon = 0, 0
for h5file in h5files:
    with h5py.File(h5file) as h5f:
        dnb_ds = h5f['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB/Data Fields/DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m']
        dnb[cnt_lat*dnb_ds_shape[0]:(cnt_lat+1)*dnb_ds_shape[0], 
            cnt_lon*dnb_ds_shape[1]:(cnt_lon+1)*dnb_ds_shape[1]] = dnb_ds
        cnt_lat += 1
        if cnt_lat % n_files_lat == 0:
           cnt_lat = 0
           cnt_lon += 1
```

**Step 4 - matplotlib/cartopy changes to plot 5x4 grid:**

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(n_files_lat*6,n_files_lon*6))
...
xgrid = np.arange(map_lon_min-2, map_lon_max+2, 2.)
ygrid = np.arange(map_lat_min-2, map_lat_max+2, 2.)
...
plt.xlim((map_lon_min,map_lon_max))
plt.ylim((map_lat_min,map_lat_max))
```

Here is the resulting image:
[image]

Comment: Ah no way I could've come up with this on my own... I really appreciate it, I'll be studying your solution line by line this weekend and have even more qns than I do now probably. How did you learn the grid shape was 5x4 btw? Was it from looking at the filenames or initial exploration of the data? I knew it from the website, but say if I didn't, how could I set n_files_lon/lat?

Comment: I figured out the grid shape when I was exploring the max/min data. When I printed the `lat_lon_arr` array. I could see how the grid of files fit together and how the file names matched the grid pattern. I used that as a shortcut to write this. Otherwise, you have to use each files lon/lat extents to figure out where they fit on the grid, then map to the `dnb` array. I decided to take a shortcut. :-)

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work. I'm just getting a "MemoryError: Unable to allocate 1.72 GiB for an array with shape (115221601, 2) and data type float64" at the end, so I will just look for a solution for that or wait until I go back to school to plot this :)

Comment: That must be an array in `matplotlib`. lats is shape=(9600,) lons is shape=(12600,)  x and y are shape=(9600, 12000); all are dtype=float64. (Note: 9600 x 12000 = 11522160). You can try removing the `#.astype(np.float32)` comment where lats and lons are defined. It's a relic from a memory error I was getting...but it was caused by a coding error and not a memory problem. (I have a 24 GB system.)

Comment: Removing #.astype(np.float32) worked. I thought it was commented out so wouldn't affect the process!

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't quite figure out how to do what @kcw78 suggested in the comments, so this is the approach I took (largely adapted from [this forum](https://hdfeos.org/forums/showthread.php?t=838)). I still don't think it's right. Plotting it doesn't work either.

```
import os
import glob                                                                 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cf
import numpy as np
import h5py

dirname = 'D:/PYTHON/NASA'
h5_files = []

i = 0
for file in list(glob.glob(dirname+'/VNP46A1.*.h5')):
    data = h5py.File(file)
    # Read dataset.
    data2D = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB/Data Fields/DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m']
    dnb = data2D[:,:].astype(np.double)
    
    # Read geolocation dataset.
    lat_max = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['NorthBoundingCoord']
    lat_min = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['SouthBoundingCoord']
    lon_min = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['WestBoundingCoord']
    lon_max = data['HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB'].attrs['EastBoundingCoord']
    latitude_max = lat_max[:]
    latitude_min = lat_min[:]
    longitude_max = lon_max[:]
    longitude_min = lon_min[:]

    # Retrieve attributes.
    attrs = list(data2D.attrs)
    aoa = data2D.attrs['add_offset']
    add_offset = aoa[0]
    fva = data2D.attrs["_FillValue"]
    _FillValue = fva[0]
    sfa = data2D.attrs["scale_factor"]
    scale_factor = sfa[0]        
    ua = data2D.attrs["units"]
    units = ua[0]
    dnb[dnb == _FillValue] = np.nan
    dnb = (dnb - add_offset) * scale_factor 
    datam = np.ma.masked_array(dnb, np.isnan(dnb))
    if i == 0 :
        data_m = datam
        latitude_max_m = latitude_max
        latitude_min_m = latitude_min
        longitude_max_m = longitude_max
        longitude_min_m = longitude_min
    else:
        data_m = np.vstack([data_m, datam])
        latitude_max_m = np.vstack([latitude_max_m, latitude_max])
        latitude_min_m = np.vstack([latitude_min_m, latitude_min])
        longitude_max_m = np.vstack([longitude_max_m, longitude_max])
        longitude_min_m = np.vstack([longitude_min_m, longitude_min])
    i = i + 1
```

Comment: You posted this while I was grinding thru your problem. :-). The key is creating a `dnb` array large enough to hold the data from ALL 20 DNB datasets. So, it should have `shape=4*shape[0],5*shape[1]` and `dtype=np.uint16` to match the datasets. Then, as you read each dataset, you use NumPy slice notation to map the H5 data to the appropriate range of the array. Also, I discovered the plot is blank when the matplotlib figure size is too small. That's why I set `figsize=(n_files_lat*6,n_files_lon*6)`. (I spent a lot of time debugging data errors trying to figure that out!)

Comment: I looked at the referenced HDFEOS code in your post. It is an interesting approach (different and maybe simpler). 3 major differences: 1) they read each array, then use `np.vstack()` to stack them; 2) They get the latitude and longitude arrays as dataset data, and you have to calculate them from the `BoundingCoord` attributes; and 3) they used `scatter()` instead of `pcolormesh()`. My primary concern: what is a memory hit is when you incrementally vstack 60 files (1 each for latitude, longitude and the DNB data)?

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way would be to use GDAL for managing the IO, a benefit is that with `gdal.BuildVRT` for example you can have GDAL do any mosaicing for you. Which might be easier in general, but especially when your input files don't form a nice filled grid (eg missing some tiles here and there).

You still have to parse the corner coordinates from the metadata manually, which is often inevitable with these custom definitions. That's probably the most error prone step.

### I/O

```py
from osgeo import gdal
from pathlib import Path
import os

def get_bbox(filename):
    "Read/parse the coordinates from the metadata, and the return
    it in the order outputBounds expects"

    meta = gdal.Info(os.fspath(filename), format='json')

    # order should match GDAL's "outputBounds" (!!)
    bbox_keys = [
        "HDFEOS_GRIDS_VNP_Grid_DNB_WestBoundingCoord",
        "HDFEOS_GRIDS_VNP_Grid_DNB_NorthBoundingCoord",
        "HDFEOS_GRIDS_VNP_Grid_DNB_EastBoundingCoord",
        "HDFEOS_GRIDS_VNP_Grid_DNB_SouthBoundingCoord",
    ]

    return list(map(lambda key: float(meta["metadata"][""][key]), bbox_keys))
```

```py
data_dir = Path(r'D:\Temp\VIIRS_DNB')
filenames = sorted(data_dir.glob("VNP46A1.A???????.h??v??.001.*.h5"))

ds_templ = "HDF5:{fn}://HDFEOS/GRIDS/VNP_Grid_DNB/Data_Fields/DNB_At_Sensor_Radiance_500m"

gdal_options = dict(
    widthPct=5,
    heightPct=5,
    resampleAlg=gdal.GRA_Average,
    format="VRT",
)

ds = gdal.BuildVRT(
    "", list(map(
        lambda fn: gdal.Translate("", ds_templ.format(fn=fn), outputBounds=get_bbox(fn), **gdal_options), 
        filenames,
    )),
)
data = ds.ReadAsArray()
gt = ds.GetGeoTransform()
ds = None
```

Note that I resample the final result to be 5% of the original size, because it would otherwise be way too large for plotting on a small image. You can remove or change the `widthPct`, `heightPct`, `resampleAlg` in the `gdal_options`.

It can be helpful, for debugging or general understanding, to write the intermediate VRT files to disk instead of doing in-memory with the empty `""`.

### Plotting

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
ys, xs = data.shape 
mpl_extent = [
    gt[0],           # ulx
    gt[0]+gt[1]*xs,  # lrx
    gt[3]+gt[5]*ys,  # lry
    gt[3],           # uly
]

map_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
data_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(8,8), dpi=96, facecolor="w", layout="compressed",
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=map_proj),
)

ax.imshow(data, extent=mpl_extent, transform=data_proj, cmap="cividis", norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=5, vmax=300))
ax.coastlines(color="w", lw=0.3)
ax.gridlines(color="w", draw_labels=True, lw=0.4, alpha=.4)
```

[image]

Comment: I got frustrated installing GDAL, but I will try again to study this solution, too. The final map looking a little blended out - is that the affect of resampleAlg?